# some keys on the laptop keyboard not working even after plugging in an external keyboard

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, keyboard, lenovo-laptop

my 's' key a few days ago was not working properly, so I took it off. but when i took it off, the 's' key keeps on getting spammed to the point that it lags my laptop.

some keys that also does not work are-
*Fn+F1(however F1 works normally if I do not press Fn key)
*Fn+Left Arrow/Up Arrow key(both also work if I do not press Fn key)
*I cannot have more than one key pressed at the same time(like let's say I am playing an FPs game I cannot press W+D at the same time, this is the same with all keys)

I tried plugging in an external keyboard but it also acts the same as the laptop keyboard. My laptop is a Lenovo IdeaPad L340 Gaming. I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling the 'standard ps/2 keyboard' driver but it did not work. I currently have KeyTweak installed with the 's' key disabled so it won't lag my laptop.

Comment: Try to clean well the contacts for the S key.

Answer (score 0):

> my 's' key a few days ago was not working properly, so I took it off.
> but when i took it off, the 's' key keeps on getting spammed ...... I
> tried plugging in an external keyboard but it also acts the same as
> the laptop keyboard.

The laptop keyboard remains connected and apparently a connection inside the laptop keyboard is still making connection even with the external keyboard.

You need to replace the laptop keyboard in order to repair this defect.